# lyric search algorithm :prompt to real lyric

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, natural-language-processing

I want to make a lyric search tool.

In other words,it is means that give some prompts and get some lyrics which exist in the real world.

**For example:**

**Input:** some lyrics from coldplay ,give me power

**Output:**

Lights will guide you home

And ignite your bones

And I will try to fix you

I am a NLP newbie.And I want to use BERT to solve this problem but i don't know how to continue to do it.

My idea is bulid a structure as following:

[image]

And calculate  cosine similarity between output.

But it dosen't work well.

So I have another idea.

Powerful chatGPT can recommand lyric but it does not work well in other non-English language lyrics.

Now my idea is use chatGPT to generate a lyric, translate the generated lyric into a specified language, and then compare the generated lyric with the lyric datasets to select the most similar one.

But this method is complex and it's hard to guarantee the accuracy of the search.

Is there any better way？Is there another way to do this without chatgpt?
Or are there any similar papers?I only found the papers about ai generate lyric.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What have you tried? What do you understand about BERT? We want to help you but you have to communicate with us.  The answer. Generally speaking is yes. I've written similar systems for searching legal text which is just as obtuse.   

Do you know what a semantic embedding is?

Comment: @Conic Thank you for your comment. I added more details. I don't know semantic embedding.I'm going to learn it.Are there any recommended papers about semantic embedding ?

Comment: @AnshumanKumar Thank you for your comment. I added more details.

Answer (score 1):

I tried it myself by giving the lyrics specifying the language and then, asking what comes after those lyrics. It also gives the translation. This can be solved using ChatGPT.

Coming to your other point. Yes, we can do it without ChatGPT. You just need to create good embeddings of the other lyrics and find similarity between them. You can do that with training models like BERT and adding ArcFace loss to them.

But, since you have ChatGPT, I wouldn't recommend that.